# Why does get not provide any parameters

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have been posting data to my MVC Controller with no issue (using ajax post and HttpPost).

The issue I have is, it's asynchronous and I need it to post and wait for a response.

As such, there is `get`

However, when I do this, there is never a parameter passed.

My Javascript is

```
//the type is "GET"
function toDatabase(type, url, data, successDelegate, failDelegate, errorDelegate) {
    $.ajax({
        type: type.toUpperCase(),
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json;",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            successDelegate(response); removeSpinner();
        },
        failure: function (e) {
            failDelegate(e.statusText); removeSpinner();
        },
        error: function (e) {
            errorDelegate(e.statusText); removeSpinner();
        }
    })
}
```

and my controller is

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult SaveNewStagePlan(string name)
{
    //todo save
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        return Json(new { id = -99 });  //always returns as name is null
}
```

What have I done wrong? It worked fine when it was posting (and using HttpPost).

**Edit**

The value of data is `{"name":"MyBand"}`, created by another function which passes `JSON.stringify({ 'name': localVariableBandName })`

Comment: what is the values passed in the  `data` parameter of your `toDatabase` method ?

Comment: @Shyju, I updated my post

Comment: did you try skipping the `stringify` step?  you aren't sending json in the url parameters... using the `data` property with a GET request should change the url to `url?name=MyBand` if you don't stringify it.

Comment: Don't stringify. The client-side code works for me and does exactly what it's supposed to do. I'm passing an object as data: `{ hello: "world"}` It arrives on the server just fine.

Comment: How exactly are you calling `toDatabase()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JSON.stringify` method takes a js object and return the stringified version of that object. For example, if you pass the js object `{ name: 'shyju' }` to this method, you will get the string `{"name":"shyju"}`

When the ajax call is of GET type, the data is sent as querystring values. `$.ajax` method will convert the js object you pass in the `data` property to querystring key-value pairs as needed and send it.

So basically your current code is sending the querystring like this

```
Home/SaveNewStagePlan?{"name":"shyju"}`
```

So you can clearly see that this is not a valid querystring! Ideally It should have been `Home/SaveNewStagePlan?name=shyju`

So the solution is to pass the js object as it is (instead of the stringified version of the object) to the `$.ajax` call.

This should work.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: { name: 'shyju' },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    failure: function(e) {
    },
    error: function(e) {
    }
});
```

Since it is sending the data as querystring, you do not need to specify the `contentType` as "application json"(it will still work with it though).

Also there is no need to explicitly specify `dataType` as json as your code is always returning json data.

Also if your action method is a GET action method, you need to explicitly specify that you want to return JSON data from that. You can use the overload of Json method which takes the `JsonRequestBehavior` enum value.

```
 return Json(new { id = -99 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: When I do this, it hits my controller fine, but it always returns to the error delegate with a 500 status... :(

Comment: You need to fix your server code. See the updated answer.

Comment: OH CRUMBS... I have used `allowget` as well previously  :( Thank you (again)